# Is it possible to Store Enum value in String?

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

Actually my java program like...

```
public class Schedule {
    public static enum RepeatType {
        DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY;
    }

    public static enum WeekdayType {
        MONDAY(Calendar.MONDAY), TUESDAY(Calendar.TUESDAY), 
        WEDNESDAY(Calendar.WEDNESDAY), THURSDAY(Calendar.THURSDAY),
        FRIDAY(Calendar.FRIDAY), SATURDAY(Calendar.SATURDAY), SUNDAY(Calendar.SUNDAY);

        private int day;

        private WeekdayType(int day) {
            this.day = day;
        }

        public static List<Date> generateSchedule(RepeatType repeatType,List<WeekdayType> repeatDays) {
            // ...
            // here some logic i wrote
        }
    }
}
```

And i'm calling the method into my Business class like following...

```
@RemotingInclude
public void createEvent(TimetableVO timetableVO) {
    if ("repeatDays".equals(timetableVO.getSearchKey())) {
        List<Date> repeatDaysList = Schedule.generateSchedule(timetableVO.getRepeatType() , timetableVO.getRepeatDays());
    }
}
```

And Finally `TimetableVO` is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EC_TIMETABLE")
public class TimetableVO extends AbstractVO {
    // ...
    private RepeatType repeatType;

    // But in this case the method generateSchedule(-,-) was not calling.
    private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays;
    // ... 
}
```

So my Question is Which one is Better Statement in the Following...

```
 private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays;
```

(or)

```
 // If we give like this `How to Convert Enum type to String` because generateSchedule() method taking enum type value....
 private String repeatDays;
```

Comment: What problem were you facing while calling the method? Seems like it should work. And of course the first one is the better way.

Comment: Thankyou... if Using First one the method not executed i'm also using the debug tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of any enumerated type can be converted to a String using the toString() method. You might not have realized (I didn't at first) that if you declare a `RepeatType` variable `r1`, then `r1` can be converted to a `String` using the `toString()` method E.G. `r1.toString()`

This Program:

```
public class Main {

    /** Creates a new instance of Main */
    public Main() {
    }

    public static enum RepeatType {
        DAILY, WEEKLY, MONTHLY;
    }    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        RepeatType r1;
        r1 = RepeatType.DAILY;
        System.out.printf("R1 VALUE: %s\n", r1.toString());

        r1 = RepeatType.WEEKLY;
        System.out.printf("R1 VALUE: %s\n", r1.toString());

        r1 = RepeatType.MONTHLY;
        System.out.printf("R1 VALUE: %s\n", r1.toString());


    }

}
```

Will Output the actual Enum  Values as Follows:

```
R1 VALUE: DAILY
R1 VALUE: WEEKLY
R1 VALUE: MONTHLY
```

Comment: Are you only using Repeat Type within the Bean class? If so, just define the Enum  RepeatType within (inside) the Bean class.  If you are also using RepeatType outside the Bean class, it may help to declare RepeatType as a public enum

Comment: See This URL for a public enum example: (search for EnumTest)   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

Every enum type has built in methods `name()` to get the enum name as a `String` and `valueOf(String)` to go in the other direction. That's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually i'm creating String type and converting to List<WeekdayType>

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got correct Answer by using following ..

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="EC_TIMETABLE")
public class TimetableVO extends AbstractVO {
    // ...
    private RepeatType repeatType;

    // But in this case the method generateSchedule(-,-) was not calling.
    private WeekdayType repeatDays;
    // ... 
}
```

And in my service method i'm converting to Enum (WeekdayType) to List so it is Easy...

```
    List<WeekdayType> weekdayList= new ArrayList<WeekdayType>();
    weekdayList.add(timetableVO.getRepeatDays());
List<Date> repeatDaysList = Schedule.generateSchedule(timetableVO.getRepeatType() , weekdayList);
```

Comment: Please mark this question as solved. (Click the check mark next to the answer that provides the solution.)